# Amcharts/Angular 2 this.checkTransform is not a function issue

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

Actually I am clueless here . How to post this question. Basically I am trying to implement Amcharts on Angular 2.

This is my code

```
this.tmpchart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv"+index, {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "addClassNames" : "true",
        "marginTop":0,
        "marginRight": 80,
        "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM",
        dataSets: [{
                title: "Markers",
                fieldMappings: this.arrFieldMappings,
                dataProvider: chartData,
                classNameField: "bulletClass",
                categoryField: "year",
                dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM"}

        ],
        panels: [{
                    showCategoryAxis: true,
                    title: "",
                    recalculateToPercents: "never",
                    addClassNames: true,
                    "percentHeight": 60,
                    stockGraphs: [{
                        id: "g0",
                        title: this.segVal,
                        //"balloonText": arrMarkersID[0][1] + "<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                        "balloonText":  "<b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                        valueField: "value0",
                        comparable: true,
                        compareField: "value0",
                        type: "smoothedLine",
                        classNameField: "bulletClass",
                        bullet: "round",
                        bulletSize: 6,
                        useDataSetColors: false,
                        compareGraph: {
                            addClassNames: true,
                            bullet: "round",
                            lineThickness: 2,
                            type: "smoothedLine",
                            classNameField: "bulletClass"
                        }
                    },
        {
                        id: "g1",
                        title: "Population",
                        //"balloonText": arrMarkersID[0][1] + "<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                        "balloonText":  "<b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                        valueField: "value1",
                        comparable: true,
                        compareField: "value1",
                        type: "smoothedLine",
                        classNameField: "bulletClass",
                        bullet: "round",
                        bulletSize: 6,
                        useDataSetColors: false,
                        compareGraph: {
                            addClassNames: true,
                            bullet: "round",
                            lineThickness: 2,
                            type: "smoothedLine",
                            classNameField: "bulletClass"
                        }
                    }],

                }],
        chartScrollbarSettings: {
            //graph: "g1"
            enabled: false
        },
        chartCursorSettings: {
            valueBalloonsEnabled: true,
            fullWidth:true,
            cursorAlpha:0.6
        },
        periodSelector: {
            selectFromStart: false,
            inputFieldsEnabled: false,
            periods: [{
                period: "MM",
                count: 1,
                label: "1 month"
            },{
                period: "MM",
                count: 3,
                label: "3 Month"
            },{
                period: "MM",
                count: 6,
                label: "6 Month"
            },{
                period: "YYYY",
                count: 1,
                label: "1 year"
            },{
                period: "Max",
                label: "Max",
                selected: true
            }]
        }
    });
```

I have imported amcharts dependencies like following:

```
import 'amcharts3';
import 'amcharts3/amcharts/serial';
import 'amcharts3/amcharts/themes/light';
import 'amstock3';
import 'amstock3/amcharts/amstock'
```

When I am executing I am constantly getting below error

`EXCEPTION: this.checkTransform is not a function` even I am not sure even if it is a `Amcharts` related issue or `Angular2`.